# Sound stopped working in Ubuntu 16

Tags: 16.04, soundcard

Sound stopped working in Ubuntu 16 for no reason apparently. How do I fix this?

Here is what I get when I run

```
speaker-test -c 6 -D 'surround51:CARD=PCH,DEV=0'
```

```
speaker-test 1.1.0

Playback device is surround51:CARD=PCH,DEV=0
Stream parameters are 48000Hz, S16_LE, 6 channels
Using 16 octaves of pink noise
ALSA lib confmisc.c:768:(parse_card) cannot find card 'PCH'
ALSA lib conf.c:4292:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_card_driver returned error: No such device
ALSA lib confmisc.c:392:(snd_func_concat) error evaluating strings
ALSA lib conf.c:4292:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_concat returned error: No such device
ALSA lib confmisc.c:1251:(snd_func_refer) error evaluating name
ALSA lib conf.c:4292:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_refer returned error: No such device
ALSA lib conf.c:4771:(snd_config_expand) Evaluate error: No such device
ALSA lib pcm.c:2266:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM surround51:CARD=PCH,DEV=0
Playback open error: -19,No such device
```

Comment: Welcome to askubuntu! Please copy and paster terminal output rather than posting a picture of it. Thank you for helping us help you!

Answer (score 0):

The format of your command is wrong. It's telling you that the device you chose is invalid. You can get a list of valid card options with the command `aplay - L`.

For further reading see `man speaker-test` or http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man1/speaker-test.1.html

There's also some good explanation of the different options to be found on [the MythTV wiki](https://www.mythtv.org/wiki/Using_ALSA%27s_speaker-test_utility).

Comment: Thanks for the answer but still no sound

Comment: Please [edit] your post to include the output of `aplay -L` and the valid command that you tried that resulted in "still no sound". Thank you for helping us help you!